# Total Control for admins

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, user-accounts, ctrl-alt-delete

Good Day,
I am currently testing devices for QA and now checking their Control for the consumers and I would like to know if there is a way to disable or intercept specific key strokes (ie ctrl, alt, delete, shift, esc, etc...). The system operates as Windows 7 Professional and uses a Shell UI and Web UI. The consumer uses the Shell and the Web UI's to operate the machines at desired functions while the IT, QA and QC departments manage issues from the Windows side with 2 admin accounts that have total control. The consumer uses an account where they cannot (or should not) access the windows side. 
I have already set the gpedit.msc to stop the Task manager, lock, and other actions when ctrl-alt-del is enabled. That is good but not enough. Is there a way (and how) to stop these keystroke commands from being enabled in the User accounts and not the Admin Accounts?

Comment: it's not possible to disable the secure desktopl within Windows.  "that is good but not enough" - It's going to have to be "good enough".  "Is there a way (and how) to stop these keystroke commands from being enabled in the User accounts and not the Admin Accounts?" - There is not.

Comment: Maybe you could also check (and possibly ask) at [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I have been to all the typical websites that you think would provide an answer. It seems like the best I can do so far (without 3rd party programs) is disabling all functions of Ctrl-alt-del in the regedit so all the customers get is a nice blue screen of nothing. But thanks for the quick input!!